# Making UITableViewCell a square based on screen width

Tags: swift, ios8, uitableview

I have a table view controller displaying square videos, and I want each table view cell to be a square as well. Is it possible to have each UITableViewCell dynamically resize according to the width of the screen (for example 320x320 for iPhone5 and 375x375 for iPhone6)?

In my view controller's viewDidLoad function I have:

```
    frameWidth = self.view.frame.size.width
    self.videosView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.videosView.estimatedRowHeight = frameWidth
```

The constraints for the view that displays the video inside the UITableViewCell are:
Leading and trailing space to superview, top space to superview, 1:1 aspect ratio

I still can't get the cell to be a square though. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not just set a static row height after determining what screen size you have on the device with a switch?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this tableview method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
}
```

**Note: Method in Swift 3**

Answer (score 0):

There is a good reason that this is hard to do. Cells inside UITableView is reused so it can be allocated once. (for performance)
Resizing view is performance wise costly, that's way you only put one number as height of cell.

What you can do is to have if statement and return accordingly to phone version.

Answer (score 0):

try to use it with bounds instead of frame

```
frameWidth = view.bounds.size.width
```